# UiPath unattended automation

Tags: automation, uipath

I was just curious about how does Uipath process render GUI to interact with various application in unattended mode without screen. I am trying to build my own RPA system for few specific use cases but I am stuck at running those process in unattended. Because to interact with application(click etc) it requires GUI to render.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [article](https://www.uipath.com/kb-articles/interactive-sessions) (and a little bit simplified) they either use the console session (which is a well-known solution / workaround) or they create RDP Sessions programmatically using the FreeRDP framework. (I have tried my luck with FreeRDP but most of it's features are disabled in corporate environments)

If you really want to dig  in the whole thing, Microsoft provides a framework [for implementing own Remoting Solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd919947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Theoretically you could implement your own protocol with lower security boundaries and by not destroying the GUI if the remote session is not active (disconnected but not closed)

Comment: Thanks Bela for very informative answer. It clears a lot of doubts. I also tried FreeRDP solution. Was having similar issues. Do you know how we can implement our own protocol. Could you please point me to any sample code/article about same? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately not. There are some questions on stackoverflow and scarce resources on the net, but no real solutions. I assume the problem is not trivial - although the tutorial presents it as one: Register the new Protocol in the Registry, implement the proper call sequences and then make sure all of this is properly installed on target machines (registry and dlls)

As a workaround you may use the cmdkey command line utility. This one stores credentials in your users store and mstsc accepts it (it does not prompt for user input) - aka you could automate creating rdp sessions programmatically

Answer (score 0):

It's based on the coordinates of the controls and the text they contain. It recognizes graphical objects by their platform-specific attributes. In very particular scenarios, where object recognition is not available such as with RDP, it uses image and OCR text-based automation.

Comment: HI Akish, thanks for the answer. I know that it works based on selectors/images. I was curious about how uipath perform those action when there is no screen rendered. I think bela has provided a good overview. Please read about attended and unattended automation.